# How to make use of .jsp LDAP code and other java files in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsp, background-process

I am very exited to join this community. Here is my problem.
I am doing a project in ruby on rails which basically is to develop an interface to take applications from people then run some algorithm like Gale-Shapely for example in background after deadline and then output the results in a new page. I had the gale shapely algo coded in Java and C++ languages. The problem is we have to contact LDAP server in our institute in-order to verify the credentials of the person who is willing to fill the form. And there is a proper Java code written for that purpose which should only be used in order to contact LDAP server as per our insti rules. I ran the .jsp code by installing tomcat7 and it is working perfectly. But, now the problem I had written some code for filling form etc.. in ruby on rails. But, I am not able to use this .jsp file in the login form in rails. I searched a lot on net but I didnt found any.

Apart from this another problem is how to run my java Gale-Shapely code in background? One solution is again re-writing the entire code in ruby and use database info to run algo. Is there any method that I can give my database info to this java  program and capture its output?

Comment: Did you see this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800847/jsp-tools-for-a-ruby-rails-developer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Yaa I looked but It did not answer my questions. I want to know how to use a .jsp code in ruby on rails for LDAP purpose. And the question says ways to learn Java..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using netldap gem present in rails. I realized that similar to the java code which uses an LDAP library, there is this netldap library in ruby. So, I used it to get the credentials and verify the identity of person and also to get other details from LDAP server.